# A simple diagram

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to create this simple diagram:

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Comment: Hi, I want exactly to create that diagram in latex.

Comment: for a suggestion `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
\draw[nodes={fill=white}]
(30:1) node{$\{a\}$}--
(90:1) node{$\{a,b,c\}$}--
(150:1) node{$\{a,b\}$}--
(210:1) node{$\{a\}$}--
(270:1) node[below]{$\varnothing$}--
(330:1) node{$\{c\}$} --cycle;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect.

Comment: Use the windows TikZEd editor....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is [tikz-cd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = small, arrows = -]
& \{a,b,c\}\\
\{a,b\}\ar[ru] && \{a,c\}\ar[lu]\\
\{a\}\ar[u] && \{c\}\ar[u]\\
& \emptyset\ar[lu]\ar[ru]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The [xypic](https://ctan.org/pkg/xypic?lang=en) package is quite good at this sort of diagram.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix @R=5mm @C=4mm {
& \{a,b,c\} \ar@{-}[rd] \ar@{-}[ld] \\
\{a,b\} \ar@{-}[d]  & & \{a,c\} \ar@{-}[d] \\
\{a\}   \ar@{-}[rd] & & \{c\}   \ar@{-}[ld] \\
& \emptyset}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much xy package :-)

Answer (score 3):

A `pstricks`  solution, based on the `\psDefBoxNodes`, which defines 12 nodes in the bounding box of a text, and a `matrix` environment:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\[
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{matrix}
  & \psDefBoxNodes{T}{\{a,b,c\}} & \\
   \psDefBoxNodes{P1}{\{a,b\}} & & \psDefBoxNodes{P2}{\{a,c\}}\\
\psDefBoxNodes{S1}{\{a\}} & & \psDefBoxNodes{S2}{\{c\}} \\
  & \psDefBoxNodes{B}{\varnothing}
\end{matrix}
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linejoin=1, labelsep=3pt}
\uput[u](B:tC){\pnode{E}}\uput[d](T:bC){\pnode{U}}
\uput[u](P1:tC){\pnode{Q1}}\uput[u](P2:tC){\pnode{Q2}}
\uput[d](P1:bC){\pnode{Q3}}\uput[d](P2:bC){\pnode{Q4}}
\uput[u](S1:tC){\pnode{T1}}\uput[u](S2:tC){\pnode{T2}}
\uput[d](S1:bC){\pnode{T3}}\uput[d](S2:bC){\pnode{T4}}
\psline(Q1)(U)(Q2)
\psline(Q3)(T1)\psline(Q4)(T2)
\psline(T3)(E)(T4)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]